# Why is my regex comparison returning a parse error in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I created a [regex statement to check the format of an ID](https://regex101.com/r/mZ3hE3/2#pcre), with plans to use it to validate an input to my PHP file. In my PHP file, I have an if condition which makes use of the regex statement.

**Regex statement**

```
([1-9]{2}|50)-[0-9]{3,4}$
```

**PHP using the regex statement**

```
elseif(preg_match("([1-9]{2}|50)-[0-9]{3,4}$", $idstring) == false){
    echo "<p>Error:</p>";               
}
```

The if condition is supposed to be entered when the value of $idstring is not of the expected format, instead, I get an error message which says that the left curly brace (in the regex statement) is unexpected.

**Error message**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/username/public_html/test.php on line 33
```

Comment: `preg_match('/([1-9]{2}|50)-[0-9]{3,4}$/', $idstring)`

Comment: See more about [regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: I bet you wonder why the forward slashes were added via @anubhava comment.